# How to concatenate a LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++

How would I take...

`string modelPath = "blah/blah.obj"`

and concatenate it with...

```
L" not found."
```

While passing it in as LPCWSTR. I tried to do

```
(LPCWSTR)(modelPath + " was not found.").c_str()
```

However that did not work. Here is a larger example of what it looks like now.

```
if(!fin)
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Models/WheelFinal.txt not found.", 0, 0); //
    return;
}
```

Comment: Does `modelPath` have to be a `std::string` or can it be a `std::wstring`?

Comment: It could be wstring. Why? Should I be using wstring for this?

Comment: Because you're using it with a function that takes a wide string.

Comment: Or use `MessageBoxA` and chuck the cast, and regardless, i honestly can't remember if utilizing `.c_str()` of a temp object is the grandest of ideas. My gut tells me no (as did the coin flip, and I'm too tired to validate that in the standard).

Comment: @WhozCraig, It's fine as an argument, but not doing, e.g., `const wchar_t *s = (someString + L"blah").c_str();`.

Comment: @chris curse you and your double-tailed coin =P

Comment: @AndrewWilson: Only use `TCHAR` and their ilk for porting ancieent windows programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LPCWSTR` is a **L** ong **P** ointer to a **C** onstant ***W** ide* **STR** ing. [Wide strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character), at least in Win32, are 16 bits, whereas `(const) char` strings (i.e. `(C)STR` or their pointer-counterparts `LP(C)STR`) are 8 bits.

Think of them on Win32 as `typedef const char* LPCSTR` and `typedef const wchar_t* LPCWSTR`.

`std::string` is an 8-bit string (using the underlying type `char` by default) whereas `std::wstring` is a wider character string (i.e. 16-bits on win32, using `wchar_t` by default).

If you can, use `std::wstring` to concatenate a `L"string"` as a drop-in replacement.

---

#### A note on `MessageBox()`

Windows has a funny habit of defining macros for API calls that switch out underlying calls given the program's multibyte configuration. For almost every API call that uses strings, there is a `FunctionA` and `FunctionW` call that takes an `LPCSTR` or `LPWCSTR` respectively.

`MessageBox` is one of them. In Visual Studio, you can go into project settings and change your *Multi-Byte* (wide/narrow) setting or you can simply call `MessageBoxA/W` directly in order to pass in different encodings of strings.

For example:

```
LPWCSTR wideString = L"Hello, ";
MessageBoxW(NULL, (std::wstring(wideString) + L"world!").c_str(), L"Hello!", MB_OK);

LPCSTR narrowString = "Hello, ";
MessageBoxA(NULL, (std::string(narrowString) + "world!").c_str(), "Hello!", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Worth noting that internally, the `*A` versions convert to the strings to wide strings, so using the `*W` versions saves work.

Comment: @chris: Also, the `*A` versions use the so-called ANSI-codepage, not UTF-8, and some have additional restrictions.

Comment: Yup, ANSI and UTF-8 are completely different, and the general advice I see is to use UTF-8 right up to the point that you need a wide string to pass in and always use wide strings for Winapi calls, converting as late as possible.

Comment: Exactly. Some of the best practices I've used is to assume `std::string` contains UTF-8 encoding and have wrappers that deal with any Winapi calls directly that automatically convert to wide as necessary directly before the call itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change `modelPath` to `std::wstring`, it becomes easy:

```
MessageBox(nullptr, (modelPath + L" not found.").c_str(), nullptr, 0);
```

I changed your `0` pointer values into `nullptr` as well.

Since `std::string` represents a narrow string, `std::wstring` represents a wide string, and the two are wildly different, casting from one representation to the other does not work, while starting with the appropriate one does.  On the other hand, one can properly convert between representations using the new [`<codecvt>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/codecvt) header in C++11.