# Function works perfectly but changes value after return

Tags: c++, return

I have a function to concatenate two `LPCWSTR`s together by converting them to `wstring`s, adding them, converting it back, and then returning that value (taken from: [How to concatenate a LPCWSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999996/how-to-concatenate-a-lpcwstr/23000077))

```
LPCWSTR addLPCWSTRs(LPCWSTR lpcwstr1, LPCWSTR lpcwstr2) {
    //Add the strings together
    std::wstring wstringCombined = std::wstring(lpcwstr1) + std::wstring(lpcwstr2);
    //Convert from wstring back to LPCWSTR
    LPCWSTR lpcwstrCombined = wstringCombined.c_str();
    return lpcwstrCombined;
}

    LPCWSTR BaseURL = L"https://serpapi.com/search.json?tbm=isch?q=";
    LPCWSTR imageQuery = L"baby+animals";

   LPCWSTR URL = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery);
```

Before the return statement, the `lpcwstrCombined` value is correct, when I break before the return statement the debugger shows the value also to be correct.

The correct value should be:

[image: correct value]

When I break on the ending curly brace, the value that `lpcwstr` turns into a bunch of squares before `1-5` random symbols from other languages, and it's always changing.

Examples:

[image][image][image][image]

And this is without changing any code, simply resetting the debugger and running again. I have done hours of research on this and so far haven't found anything. A somewhat similar issue with arrays said to use pointers instead of face values but that didn't make a difference. Why does the variable change value outside of the function as soon as it is returned??

**Edit:**
After reading the comments I changed it to:

```
std::wstring addLPCWSTRs(LPCWSTR lpcwstr1, LPCWSTR lpcwstr2) {
    //Add the strings together
    std::wstring wstringCombined = std::wstring(lpcwstr1) + std::wstring(lpcwstr2);
    //Convert from wstring back to LPCWSTR
    return wstringCombined;
}

LPCWSTR BaseURL = L"https://serpapi.com/search.json?tbm=isch?q=";
LPCWSTR imageQuery = L"baby+animals";
LPCWSTR URL = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery).c_str();
```

And the same issue still happens!

Comment: When `addLPCWSTRs` returns `wstringCombined` goes out of scope and frees the memory it has managed, thus `lpcwstrCombined ` becomes a dangling pointer and you get UB.

Comment: Probably wstringCombined gets popped off the stack along with the enclosed C-buffer being freed.

Comment: You return a dangling pointer. It points to a local string, which is destroyed after returning. In the linked Q&A they do `(a + b).c_str()` without wrapping it into a function, which doesn't have this problem (as long as you use the string immediately, instead of saving the pointer for later).

Comment: `wstringCombined.c_str();`  References to pointer contained by a local variable of the function. I'd suggest ` return wstringCombined` and at the caller take `.c_str()`

Comment: Alrighty, so I have a dangling pointer, is it possible to save the value or would I need to return the `wstring` and then call `.c_str()` each time?

Comment: Yes, you need to return `wstring`.

Comment: That still gets me the same error

Comment: Note that `LP*` is referring to (long) pointer, which is just a pointer. You need to take care of its lifetime.

Comment: What does that mean? "Take care of its lifetime"?

Comment: @DaMahdi03 if you change the function to return a `std::wstring` and are still having problems, then you are using it wrong.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I added my progress, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DaMahdi03 `LPCWSTR URL = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery).c_str();` is still a dangling pointer, as the returned `wstring` is temporary. Save it to a `wstring` variable: `wstring URL = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery);` and then use `URL.c_str()` as needed. Why are you trying to do everything in `LPCWSTR` to begin with? This is not C, use `wstring` instead

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is a misunderstanding of the lifetime of your memory. In your first example you have a dangling pointer:

```
    std::wstring combined = ... 
    // Here you create the string (importantly, its memory)
    
    LPCWSTR lpcwstrCombined = wstringCombined.c_str(); 
    // Make a pointer to the string
    
    return lpcwstrCombined; 
    // return the pointer

 } // end of function the string is destroyed, including it's memory being freed
```

In your second example you do the same thing, just in a different way:

```
LPCWSTR URL = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery).c_str();
              // ^ This is a temporary, at the end of this statement, it will be 
              // destroyed along with its memory.
```

You need to keep the `wstring` arround:

```
std::wstring string_storage = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery);
LPCWSTR URL = string_storage.c_str();
```

You can then use the URL for the scope of the string.

That means don't do something like this:

```
LPCWSTR URL;
{
    std::wstring string_storage = addLPCWSTRs(BaseURL, imageQuery);
    URL = string_storage.c_str();
} // string is destoryed leaving a dangling pointer (just to get you a third 
  // time)
```